# GeoDjango confronts UnicodeEcodeError

Tags: python, django, unicode, windows-8, geodjango

I was confronting an error when I followed the LayerMapping instruction [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/).

The error says:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\xc3' in position 39: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I have found some solutions, but none of these solve my situation.

I use:

- Windows 8
- python 3.4
- and I am Taiwanese, so I use 'cp950'

I found the official instruction [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/unicode/). It says I should change my LANG environment variable from `msbc` to `en_US.UTF-8`.

However, I realized that Windows uses `msbc`, and I shouldn't change this system statement.(I can't find how to change my LANG environment variable in Windows 8)

How can I solve this problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\User\django\geodjango\world\load.py", line 27, in run
    lm.save(verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Users\User\django\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\ut
ils\layermapping.py", line 627, in save
    _save()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\contextlib.py", line 30, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\User\django\django_venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\ut
ils\layermapping.py", line 589, in _save
    stream.write('Failed to save %s:\n %s\nContinuing\n' % (kwargs, msg))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp950' codec can't encode character '\xc3' in position 3987
: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: Please provide the *full* traceback of the error, not just the exception message.

Comment: That section of the Django documentation only applies to Unix platforms. On Windows, you just need to make sure you pass Unicode objects as file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an error in LayerMapping, but then the error message can't be written to stdout, due to encoding issues.

I'm not sure how Django handles stdout or its encoding but a workaround would be to pass a specific log file with UTF-8 encoding, to the LayerMapping module

E.g.

```
lm_log = io.open("lm.log", "a", encoding="UTF-8")
LayerMapping.save(stream=lm_log)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked!
So let me make it clear, 
The save function needs to write the shape file,
but my when it opened the shape file, it used the 'msbc' encoding?